# Cancel vertex drag for an editable polyline

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using the Leaflet.Editable plugin and am trying to figure out if I can cancel a polyline drag action when the user has clicked on either the first or last point of the line. I only want them to be able to drag 'mid-points' along the line, the ends of the line need to stay fixed in the original locations.

I have seen the `editable:vertex:dragstart` event but this doesn't seem to allow me to cancel the event. I think it's because the argument passed to this event handler is not of type `cancelablevertexevent` and so does not have a `cancel()` method I can invoke.

There are click and `editable:vertex:click` and `editable:vertex:rawclick` events but these fire after the `dragstart` event (which they would since you need to release the mouse button!)

I tried returning `false` in my handler for a given condition:

```
section.on('editable:vertex:dragstart', (e) => {
    if(e.vertex.latlngs[0] === e.vertex.latlng) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work, anyone out there know if this is possible or what I need to be doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of canceling the event, you could disable the draggable feature on the vertices you want. To achieve that on an editable polyline defined as

```
var section = L.polyline(/* your coords */).addTo(map);
section.enableEdit();
```

grab the first and last points:

```
var coords = section.getLatLngs();
var disabled = [coords[0], coords[coords.length-1]];
```

and, since the vertices inherit from `L.Marker`, you can call [`vertex.dragging.disable();`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker-property) :

```
disabled.forEach(function(latlng) {
    var vertex = latlng.__vertex;
    vertex.dragging.disable();
});
```

Finally, a demo

```js
var startPoint = [43.1, 1.2];
var map = L.map('map', {editable: true}).setView(startPoint, 9),
    tilelayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 11, attribution: 'Data \u00a9 <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"> OpenStreetMap Contributors </a> Tiles \u00a9 HOT'}).addTo(map);


var section = L.polyline([[43.0, 1.15], [43.1, 1.2], [43.2, 1.5],[43.25, 1.2]]).addTo(map);
section.enableEdit();

var coords = section.getLatLngs();
var disabled = [coords[0], coords[coords.length-1]];
// icon from http://www.iconarchive.com/show/vista-map-markers-icons-by-icons-land/Map-Marker-Chequered-Flag-Right-Chartreuse-icon.html
var goalpost = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/24/Map-Marker-Chequered-Flag-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png',
    iconSize: [24, 24],
    iconAnchor: [0, 24],
});
disabled.forEach(function(latlng) {
    var vertex = latlng.__vertex;
    vertex.dragging.disable();
    vertex.setIcon(goalpost);
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-editable/1.1.0/Leaflet.Editable.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

---

Or if you feel that the usage of an internal property is too dangerous, you could extend `L.Editable.PolylineEditor` to override the methods responsible for the creation of the vertices and pass that to your polyline:

```
var AnchoredPolylineEditor = L.Editable.PolylineEditor.extend({
    addVertexMarker: function (latlng, latlngs, opts) {
        return new this.tools.options.vertexMarkerClass(latlng, latlngs, this, opts || {});
    },
    addVertexMarkers: function (latlngs) {
        for (var i = 0, l = latlngs.length; i < l; i++) {
            this.addVertexMarker(latlngs[i], latlngs, {
                draggable: (i>0) && (i<l-1)
            });
        }
    }
});

var section = L.polyline([[43.0, 1.15], [43.1, 1.2], [43.2, 1.5],[43.25, 1.2]], {
    editorClass: AnchoredPolylineEditor
}).addTo(map);
section.enableEdit();
```

And a demo

```js
var startPoint = [43.1, 1.2];
var map = L.map('map', {editable: true}).setView(startPoint, 9),
    tilelayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 11, attribution: 'Data \u00a9 <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"> OpenStreetMap Contributors </a> Tiles \u00a9 HOT'}).addTo(map);
    
    
var AnchoredPolylineEditor = L.Editable.PolylineEditor.extend({
    addVertexMarker: function (latlng, latlngs, opts) {
        return new this.tools.options.vertexMarkerClass(latlng, latlngs, this, opts || {});
    },
    addVertexMarkers: function (latlngs) {
        for (var i = 0, l = latlngs.length; i < l; i++) {
            this.addVertexMarker(latlngs[i], latlngs, {
                draggable: (i>0) && (i<l-1)
            });
        }
    }
});

var section = L.polyline([[43.0, 1.15], [43.1, 1.2], [43.2, 1.5],[43.25, 1.2]], {
  editorClass: AnchoredPolylineEditor
}).addTo(map);
section.enableEdit();
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-editable/1.1.0/Leaflet.Editable.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: thanks for this, that `__vertex` looks like an internal property to me, is it officially supported?

Comment: it is indeed an internal property added by Leaflet.Editable to keep track of the vertices. Officially supported? Probably not, but it's used all over the place in the source code and should be reasonably safe to use.

Comment: Hi, I am also looking into that same case but for the cancel delete event on vertex, whenever I click on vertex it got deleted from the polygon, so cancel